# how to deploy project on local server apache tomcat 7

Tags: apache, jakarta-ee

I have dynamic web project called Test in which there is one html file demo.html
I have created Test.war file from eclipse
I want to deploy it on apache tomcat 7 so that i can run demo.html from my browser

I dont want to use eclipse for running project

Plz help.

Comment: Drop the war into the webapps directory and start Tomcat.

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/

Answer (score 0):

Drop the war into tomcat webapps directory and to start tomcat in windows use command prompt go to tomcat dir/bin then run startup.bat.if your using linux go to tomcat dir/bin then run startup.sh.

To stop tomcat run shutdown.bat/shutdown.sh